# Error on Compiling Caffe / PyCaffe

Tags: python, caffe, pycaffe

I'm trying to compile an older version of Caffe with Cuda 7.0, and Python 2.7. The thing is I keep getting this error:

```
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_python-py35
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.5m
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so] Error 1
```

The Makefile.config is the nearly the same as the example, except I'm using the OpenCV_Version := 3

I googled it, and I have no idea why the compilation is looking for something with python35/3.5

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You have the general idea: you've somehow mixed versions in the environment.  I'd attack it from that perspective: see what's included.  search your environment for "35" and "3.5" references:

```
env | egrep "35|3.5"
```

especially look at LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PATH.  Also check what packages are expected with suspicious files.  For instance,

```
ldd .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so
```

You may find that you need to remove a Python3.5 reference from your environment and rebuild earlier packages.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably have the following problem.

NOTE: If the Ubuntu operating system was updated, perhaps the Python layer needs to be updated and recompiled, because the Python module no longer works. Perform this step again in that case.

```
for req in $(cat requirements.txt); do pip install $req; done
```

In case of any problems, try:

```
for req in $(cat requirements.txt); do sudo -H pip install $req --upgrade; done
```

> The default Python version is 2. You can edit the Makefile.conf to
>   enable the Python 3, but this will fail during the linking phase:
>   **boost_python3** cannot be found on Ubuntu 16.04. Instead, this file
>   should be **/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py35.so.1.58.0.**
>   This requires further testing.

Check [link](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Ubuntu-16.04-or-15.10-Installation-Guide) for more information.